# I want to checked my all checkbox from one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function chk() {
  var a = $('#chkAll').prop('checked');

  if (a == true)
    $('.hobbie').attr('checked', 'checked');
  else
    $('.hobbie').removeAttr('checked');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select All <input onclick="chk()" type="checkbox" id="chkAll">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
```

If I clicked on select all checkbox its selecting all checkbox and if I click again it unchecked all checkbox but after that its not working till I refresh the page.

Comment: you are removing the attribute checked in else condition, so it wont trigger second time. just toggle true/false. 

function chk(){
   var a=$('#chkAll').prop('checked');

        if(a==true)
            $('.hobbie').attr('checked','true');
        else
            $('.hobbie').attr('checked', 'false);
 }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to check if condition. Shortest way to do this.

```js
function chk() {
  $('#chkAll').on('change', function() {
    $('.hobbie:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onclick="chk()" type="checkbox" id="chkAll">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
```

Comment: It already has `onClick` then you used `change` function, so no need to use double function here.

Comment: I agree @Pedram, there is no need for the use of 2 events like this.

Answer (score 7):

Use this code:

```
function chk(obj) {
  $('.hobbie').prop('checked', $(obj).prop('checked'));
}
```

**demo**

```js
function chk(obj) {
  $('.hobbie').prop('checked', $(obj).prop('checked'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select All <input onclick="chk(this)" type="checkbox" id="chkAll">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
```

Comment: This is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

try simple code:

```
    $("#chkAll").click(function () {
        $(".hobbie").attr('checked', this.checked);
        //or
        $(".hobbie").prop('checked', true);
    });
```

Comment: how to unchecked it again

Comment: $(".hobbie").prop('checked', false);

Answer (score 0):

One liner `function`

```js
function chk(isChecked) {
  $('.hobbie').prop('checked', isChecked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select All <input onclick="chk(this.checked)" type="checkbox" id="chkAll">
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
<input type="checkbox" class="hobbie">
```